# How can i create an activated checkpoint system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[I have been trying to place this script on an invisible object to mark that as a checkpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfYDN.png)

[And with this script i am trying to use the return key to go back to the previously touched checkpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsYD3.png)

when i try to do this however it does not seem to want to work and i'm not entirely sure why, it keeps telling me that spawnPoint is not assigned to anything but that's what should be happening in the CheckPoint script. Please Help

Comment: Please post your code using the [code sample option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) of Stack Overflow, it's a lot easier for us to help you like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `spawnPoint` in the `GoToCheckpoint` script seem to have no link to the `spawnPoint` of the `Checkpoint` script. Unless you assigned something in the inspector it's normal that it returns that error.

Something simple you could do to access the `spawnPoint` of the `Checkpoint` script from the `GoToCheckpoint` script, would be to change it to a static field.

Change the `spawnPoint` of you `Checkpoint` script and remove the other `spawnPoint` of the other script you won't need it.

```
public static Transform spawnPoint;
```

Then from the `GoToCheckpoint` script you can call it from inside your update function

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
    {
        Debug.Log("returning to checkpoint");
        tf.position = Checkpoint.spawnPoint.position;
    }
}
```